# Links in the right sidebar are hard to see

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is particularly prevalent in the Similar Questions sidebar:

[image]

I find it very hard to distinguish the link text from the background which looks too dark to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have brightened the link color significantly. The change will be in the next deployment.